# Unable to get Material-Ui datepicker date on the first change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, material-ui

So I am unable, to get date from material-ui dateandtimepicker on the first select, somehow, i get value only on second click, and that value is previous one,
Also would love to know if there is any other way to convert date to format like this yyyy:mm:dd:hh:mm without using moment.js

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DataPicker from './UI-components/DataPicker'

class EventForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: '',
      errors: {},
      start:'',
      end:''
    }
  }

  onChange1(e) {
    this.setState({
      start: e.target.value,
    });
    console.log(this.state.start)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DataPicker
          label="Event Starts"
          onChange={this.onChange1.bind(this)} 
          defaultas="2017-05-24T10:30"
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default EventForm;
```

DatePicker.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
    width: 300,
  },
});

function DateAndTimePickers(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <form className={classes.container} noValidate>
      <TextField
        id="datetime-local"
        label={props.label}
        type="datetime-local"
        defaultValue={props.defaultas}
        className={classes.textField}
        onChange = {props.onChange} 
        value = {props.value} 
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true,
        }}
      />
    </form>
  );
}

DateAndTimePickers.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(DateAndTimePickers);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing down the `value` to the `DatePicker` component. You could use `start` as `value` to control the `DatePicker` and ignore the `defaultValue` entirely.

The reason why `console.log(this.state.start)` in your `onChange1` handler isn't displaying the `start` you would think is because `setState` is asynchronous, which means `this.state.start` will not have been updated yet.

```
class EventForm extends Component {
  state = {
    text: '',
    errors: {},
    start: '2017-05-24T10:30',
    end: ''
  };

  onChange1 = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      start: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DataPicker
          label="Event Starts"
          onChange={this.onChange1}
          value={this.state.start}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: But now I am getting  Input contains an input of type datetime-local with both value and defaultValue props. Input elements must be either controlled or uncontrolled (specify either the value prop, or the defaultValue prop, but not both)
And  i Would love to use default value, and set it to todays date

Comment: Did exactly that, and now getting
this.setState is not a function and Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development
I am using webpack by the way

Comment: Okay, im getting no errors, got errors when used Osman's function

Answer (score 1):

i don't know much about react but this might help with the formatting of the dates;

```
<td>
{new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { 
    year: 'numeric', 
    month: 'long', 
    day: '2-digit' 
}).format(customer.firstSale)}
</td>
```

Example from [here](https://www.carlrippon.com/formatting-dates-and-numbers-in-react/);

Answer (score 0):

Well you are getting old one means last set value in state cause you are doing things simultaneously/parallelly both set value and console value. Means you know JS is async you are doing here

```
 onChange1(e) {
    this.setState({
      start: e.target.value,
    });
    console.log(this.state.start)
  }
```

what is happening here setting the new value to state and console current/last/default(first time) state value, That's why you are getting it the second time.

to get current one do like this:

```
onChange1(e) {
        this.setState({
          start: e.target.value,
        },function(whatever){
          console.log(this.state.start)
        });
     }
```

it will execute and console value once your set state is done.

And for formatting date without `momentjs` you can find the source of `momentjs` what they are doing under the hood obviously they are using JS. If I were you I'll do this way. Haha